# Having issues trying to create a template function using member functions

Tags: c++

I'm making a network using TCP sockets in c++.
I'm having issues when I'm trying to hold my packet handlers in a map.
Here is my implementation:

```
using handler_t = std::function<void (NetworkClient *, NetworkMessage *)>;
using handlers_t = std::unordered_map<int32_t, handler_t>;

template <typename T, typename V>
using typed_handler_t = void (T::*)(NetworkClient *, V *);

class AbstractPacketHandler {
public:
    void init() {
       define_handlers(_handlers);
    }

    void parse_packet(NetworkClient *client, NetworkMessage *msg) {
        lock_t lock(_locker);
        try {
            _handlers.at(msg->getProtocolId())(client, msg);
        } catch (std::exception &e) {
            throw std::runtime_error("no handler found for protocol id " + msg->getProtocolId());
        }
    }

    virtual void define_handlers(handlers_t &handlers) = 0;

protected:

    template <typename T, typename V>
    handler_t handler(T &holder, typed_handler_t<T, V> addr) {
        return [&holder, &addr](NetworkClient *client, NetworkMessage *msg) mutable {
            (holder.*addr)(client, dynamic_cast<V *>(msg));
        };
    }

private:
    handlers_t _handlers;
    std::mutex _locker;
};
```

Packet Handler implementation

```
using Self = MasterPacketHandler;

void Self::define_handlers(handlers_t &handlers) {
    handlers[HelloConnectMessage::PROTOCOL_ID] = handler<Self, HelloConnectMessage>(*this, &Self::onHello);
    handlers[AwesomeMessage::PROTOCOL_ID] = handler<Self, AwesomeMessage>(*this, &Self::onAwesomeMsg);
}

void Self::onHello(NetworkClient *client, HelloConnectMessage *msg) {
    printf("deserialized hellomsg: %d\n", msg->getHelloVar());
}

void Self::onAwesomeMsg(NetworkClient *client, AwesomeMessage *msg) {
    printf("deserialized awesome: %s %d\n", msg->getAwesome(), msg->getSomeNumber());
}
```

This code compiles w/o warning or error. But at runtime when I receive a message, I get a `segmentation fault`
After multiples tries to fix, I tried a debug with `valgrind`
Below the returned error:

```
==14561== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14561==    at 0x117CDD: std::function<void (NetworkClient*, NetworkMessage*)> AbstractPacketHandler::handler<SlavePacketHandler, AwesomeMessage>(SlavePacketHandler&, void (SlavePacketHandler::*)(NetworkClient*, AwesomeMessage*))::{lambda(NetworkClient*, NetworkMessage*)#1}::operator()(NetworkClient*, NetworkMessage*) (AbstractPacketHandler.h:40)
==14561== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14561==    at 0x117D3C: std::function<void (NetworkClient*, NetworkMessage*)> AbstractPacketHandler::handler<SlavePacketHandler, AwesomeMessage>(SlavePacketHandler&, void (SlavePacketHandler::*)(NetworkClient*, AwesomeMessage*))::{lambda(NetworkClient*, NetworkMessage*)#1}::operator()(NetworkClient*, NetworkMessage*) (AbstractPacketHandler.h:40)
==14561== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==14561==    at 0x0: ???
==14561==    by 0x117EEA: std::_Function_handler<void (NetworkClient*, NetworkMessage*), std::function<void (NetworkClient*, NetworkMessage*)> AbstractPacketHandler::handler<SlavePacketHandler, AwesomeMessage>(SlavePacketHandler&, void (SlavePacketHandler::*)(NetworkClient*, AwesomeMessage*))::{lambda(NetworkClient*, NetworkMessage*)#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, NetworkClient*&&, NetworkMessage*&&) (functional:1731)
==14561== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==14561==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x0
==14561==    at 0x0: ???
==14561==    by 0x117EEA: std::_Function_handler<void (NetworkClient*, NetworkMessage*), std::function<void (NetworkClient*, NetworkMessage*)> AbstractPacketHandler::handler<SlavePacketHandler, AwesomeMessage>(SlavePacketHandler&, void (SlavePacketHandler::*)(NetworkClient*, AwesomeMessage*))::{lambda(NetworkClient*, NetworkMessage*)#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, NetworkClient*&&, NetworkMessage*&&) (functional:1731)
```

In all of these errors we can see `AbstractPacketHandler:40` that is the following line of code of my `handler` method.
`(holder.*addr)(client, dynamic_cast<V *>(msg));`

I don't understand the errors, all variables are initialized since they are parameters of the function.. do my handler method is right written?

Comment: You have undefined behavior somewhere.  Can you [edit] your question to show a complete program with this problem?  Since you are not showing all your code, there's no guarantee that it's even possible to help you.

Comment: So the problem comes from an upper layout? I can show you the code when I call some handler..

Comment: edited with more code in AbstractPacketHandler

Comment: have you stepped through this in a debugger to see what's happening? Have you written unit tests to verify the thing returned from `handler` is really what you expect, and behaves as you expect? Your code obviously isn't complete since we can't see the `SlavePacketHandler` from the error message, and there could easily be a mistake in that.

Comment: This question is off-topic if no one is able to reproduce the problem described.

Comment: The problem was simply `return [&holder, &addr](NetworkClient *client, NetworkMessage *msg) mutable ` I had to change `&addr` to `addr` in the capture..

Comment: for some reasons, we cant create references of pointer to member function

Comment: `addr` is a passed by value and is then a local variable. You are capturing a dangling reference.